# GWT - Way around Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: gwt, gdata

I'm making an internet application with GWT, and one of the features that I've been stuck on for a few weeks is getting the users contact data from google data. I've tried things like GWT-GData and they don't seem to play nicely with the current version of GWT, so I tried going the more traditional approach with OAuth and doing an HTTP Get request. I haven't been receiving anything back as a response, and couldn't figure out why, and I happened across my javascript error log and I'm getting:

"Origin [site name here] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

I've done some reading and I have a decent idea of what's going on, but I don't know how to get around it in GWT. I've found plenty of read-ups on how to get around it with other platforms, but I haven't seen anything for GWT. Can anyone offer any wisdom?

Edit:
Here is the code I'm using:

```
public static void doGet(String url, String oauthToken) {

        RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);
        try {
            Request request = builder.sendRequest(oauthToken, new RequestCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Request request, Throwable e) {
                    GWT.log(e.toString(), e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                    Window.alert("HEADER:" + response.getHeadersAsString() 
                            + "\nSTATUS: " + response.getStatusText()
                            + "\nTEXT: " + response.getText());
                }
            });
        } catch (RequestException e) {
            GWT.log(e.toString(), e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do but configure the server to accept the origin of the request (i.e. add it to the returned `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Because it's GData, it might however simply be a mistake on your side re. the requested URL: there's no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` when you request data in Atom format, only when requesting JSON (and the value is then `*` which allows everyone, so shouldn't cause any issue like you're seeing): http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45980#c2

Comment: I've added the code that I'm using to the original post. What could be wrong with it? The address I'm trying to access is: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/[emailhere]%40gmail.com/full

Comment: As I said, requesting Atom isn't allowed: add `?alt=json` to the URL; but how about using http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gdata/ ? BTW, the first argument to `send()` is useless with `Method.GET`.

Comment: I've tried gwt-data. I couldn't get it working on app engine. Only locally for some reason. When I compiled and sent to server it started getting javascript errors. When I get home ill try the ?alt=json

Comment: Yup, just tried it with the ?alt=json with no luck. I just don't get why I can't get this to work. I thought querying from google would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't answer the original question, the following may help others who have the same underlying issue that arrived at this page (I'm using a GWT client with a Groovy web server). This did the trick on the server:

```
HttpExchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
```